# How to flip and transform a graph

Tags: graphics

I haved plot a graph from two functions:

```
η = 52;
h = 0.5682;
dpdx = -4.092*10^(-2);

Fg = dpdx;
Fl = dpdx/η;
Bl = ((Fg - Fl) h^2 - Fg)/(2 h - 2 η*h + 2 η);
Cg = -Fg/2 - η*Bl;
Bg = η*Bl;

Ut1[y_] := Fg*y^2/2 + Bg*y + Cg;
Ut2[y_] := Fl*y^2/2 + Bl*y;

Plot1 = Plot[Ut1[y]*1000, {y, h, 1}];
Plot2 = Plot[Ut2[y]*1000, {y, 0, h}, PlotStyle -> Orange];
Show[{Plot1, Plot2}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"y", "U"}, 
 AxesStyle -> FontSize -> 14]
```

The result:

[image]

How to flip and transform the graph to this way?

[image]

PS: The numbers at the axes has to be legible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`ParametricPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot.html) to flip the axes.

```
η = 52;
h = 0.5682;
dpdx = -4.092*10^(-2);

Fg = dpdx;
Fl = dpdx/η;
Bl = ((Fg - Fl) h^2 - Fg)/(2 h - 2 η*h + 2 η);
Cg = -Fg/2 - η*Bl;
Bg = η*Bl;

Ut1[y_] := Fg*y^2/2 + Bg*y + Cg;
Ut2[y_] := Fl*y^2/2 + Bl*y;

plot3 = ParametricPlot[{Ut1[y]*1000, y}, {y, h, 1}];

plot4 = ParametricPlot[{Ut2[y]*1000, y}, {y, 0, h}, PlotStyle -> Orange];

Show[{plot3, plot4}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"U", "y"}, 
 AxesStyle -> FontSize -> 14]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can also post-process the `Show` output using [`RotationTransform`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RotationTransform.html) and [`ReflectionTransform`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReflectionTransform.html):

```
show = Show[{Plot1, Plot2}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"y", "U"}, AxesStyle -> 14];

Show[MapAt[GeometricTransformation[#, 
   Composition[ReflectionTransform[{-1, 0}], RotationTransform[Pi/2]]] &, show, {1}], 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, AxesLabel -> { "U", "y"} ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Define myFigure as your figure and then:

```
Rotate[myFigure, -90 Degree]
```

[image]